# Failed to deserialize response in JAX-WS

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, web-services, jax-ws

I created a web service which return user data by id, I used `Hibernate ORM` for DAO operations. There is only one xml file in my web service and it is `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Here is my file `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@devoradb.test:1521:orcl</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">mistest</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.ministry.MinistryPosition" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.ministry.StructureOfMinistry" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.software.ModuleInSoftware" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.software.CategoryInSoftware" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.software.Software" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.software.ColorCode" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.user.DigitalSmartCard" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.user.IdCard" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.user.UserModule" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.user.UserRole" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.user.UserSoftware" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.user.Restraining" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.user.User" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.software.ColorCode" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.user.LoginInfo" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.user.LoginToken" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.user.UserCategory" ></mapping>
        <mapping class="mis.pojos.user.LaborContract"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I run my `getUserById(long id)` webMethod in any application, I got following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.soap.DeserializationException: [failed to localize] Failed to deserialize the response.(javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,25392]
Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.])
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.getUserById(Unknown Source)
    at Test.getUserById(Test.java:13)
    at Test.main(Test.java:7)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,25392]
Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:470)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:402)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.unmarshal(BridgeImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.Bridge.unmarshal(Bridge.java:222)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.glassfish.BridgeWrapper.unmarshal(BridgeWrapper.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:635)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:104)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,25392]
Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:601)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:400)
    ... 13 more
Java Result: 1
```

I googled so many times, I can not find exact solution to my problem.

Comment: JAX-WS transmits the data as XML. It is that XML that is proving to be the problem, not your hibernate config file... (your hibernate config file doesn't have 25,392 characters in row 1.) So focus on the JAX-WS part and forget about hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I create any other method and run this there is no problem. Problem occur when use classes which mapped by hibernate. For this reason I think problem may be with hibernate.

Comment: Well, you haven't provided anything I can really use to track down the problem... what I would do, in your shoes, is to use a tool like Wireshark (or similar) to see what XML is actually going over the wire, and try to figure out why this XML is invalid. Good luck.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I had the same problem, and - unfortunately - I had to solve this by using DTO objects rather than sending "pure" database entities in web service methods. WS serializer does not seem to be a huge fan of Hibernate entities.

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie thanks for your comment. I alse solved by using DTO.

Comment: The problem's reason is that,when I am using lazy initialization for my entities this problem occurred.  There are two way to solve that. First is changing lazy to eager initialization, other way is using Data Transfer Object (DTO).